# Derive Probabilities from Bayesian Network

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

I have given the following Bayesian network.

[image: example bayesian network]

I already know the fundamentals, for example, pairwise dependencies and how to calculate the total joint probability:

$$P(M,B,S,C,H) = P(M)\cdot P(S|M)\cdot P(B|M)\cdot P(C|S,B)\cdot P(H|B)$$

But now I want to calculate $P(M|S,C,H)$. I can easily apply Bayes Theorem to get:

$$P(M|S,C,H) = \frac{P(M,S,C,H)}{P(S,C,H)}$$

But I do not know how to calculate $P(M,S,C,H)$ and $P(S,C,H)$. I tried to solve it and got $P(M|S,C,H) = 0.5$. I strongly doubt that my calculations are correct because from sampling from the network with $1.000.000$ I got a relative frequency of about $0.2$.

**EDIT:** The sampling was performed incorrectly. It just proved that $P(M=1) = 0.2$. When performed correctly, it can be shown that the correct solution can be approximated with the sampled data from the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formulae are correct. Furthermore:
$$
\begin{align}
P(M, S, C, H) &= \sum_{B} P(M, B, S, C, H)\\
P(S, C, H) &= \sum_{B, M} P(M, B, S, C, H),
\end{align}
$$
are just the marginalizations. And you already have the formula for $P(M, B, S, C, H)$.

Comment: This would mean that I get a result of $\frac{0.02432}{0.0448} \approx 0.5429$. Why does it not match with the values I got from sampling?

Comment: You should get not just one conditional probability, but $2^3=8$, one for each combination of $S, C, H$: $P(M|S=0, C=0,H=0), P(M|S=0, C=0, H=1), ..., P(M|S=1, C=1, H=1)$.

Comment: Yeah, I know but I assumed $P(M|S,C,H)=P(M=1|S=1,C=1,H=1)$ and $P(\overline{M}|\overline{S},\overline{C},\overline{H})=P(M=0|S=0,C=0,H=0)$

Comment: I don't understand. The expression $P(M|S,C,H)$ is a function with four variables, and you need to know the value for all combinations. You can use $P(M=1|S,C,H) = 1-P(M=0|S,C,H)$ because $M$ is binary, so you only have to compute eight values $P(M=0|S,C,H)$ for each combination of binary values for $S,C,H$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
P(M=1|HCS=1)\overset{Bayes' law}= &\frac{P(HCS|M)\cdot P(M)}{P(HCS)}\\
 =& \frac{P(S|M) \cdot P(C|M) \cdot P(H|M) \cdot P(M)}{P(H) \cdot P(C) \cdot P(S)}\\
\text{with:}\\
P(S|M) =& 0.2\\
P(C|M) =& 0.8 \cdot 0.8 + 0.8 \cdot 0.2\\
P(H|M) =& 0.8 \cdot 0.8 + 0.6 \cdot 0.2\\
P(M) =& 0.2\\
\text{and:}\\
P(H) =& 0.8 \cdot 0.8 + 0.2 \cdot 0.6\\
P(C) =& 0.2 \cdot 0.8 \cdot 0.8 +\\
      & 0.8 \cdot 0.8 \cdot 0.8 +\\
      & 0.2 \cdot 0.2 \cdot 0.8 +\\
      & 0.8 \cdot 0.2 \cdot 0.05\\
P(S) =& 0.2 \cdot 0.2 + 0.8 \cdot 0.05
\end{align} 
$$
With that you get $P(M=1|HCS=1) \approx 0.588$.